# What happened to e2compr?

Tags: kernel, ext4, compression

Is it a part of the kernel now? Can I enable selective file compression for either ext2, or ext3, or ext4? `chattr +c filename` does not seem to work.

I'm ok with custom kernels but it'll cause some update troubles, and I also don't see such checkboxes when I do `sudo make menuconfig` for my custom kernel (I've tried to uncheck "use ext4 for ext2 partitions, some ext2-only options appeared, but no compression options there).

Comment: It is dead, see http://e2compr.sourceforge.net/ . Also https://sources.debian.org/src/linux/5.10.26-1/Documentation/filesystems/ext2.rst/?hl=385#L385 .

Comment: So I can't even use transparent decompression? How silly :( unXZ is built into kernel since SquashFS is supported natively, "compressed" file attribute exists for years, but I can't compress a file and change it's attr "+c" in order to enable on-the-fly decompression. I understand however any modification will force kernel to decompress it fully, modify and write as decompressed, and also check if file is actually compressed or just has attr "+c" (and still waiting for compression). But both things look easy to implement.

Comment: Maybe Reiser4 be an option - see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Reiser4#Formatting .

Comment: What types of FS (except obvious ext2, ext3 and ext4) can I use as "/"? I want to make a portable system on an USB stick and I want to have a single partition there. Can Ubuntu be installed on Reiser4? „It is still not included in the official Linux kernel, but patches for Linux-5.x is already available“ makes me doubt, but what if those patches are included in Ubuntu builds by default?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments already, [e2compr](http://e2compr.sourceforge.net/) unfortunately never made it into the mainline kernel.  It touched too many other parts of the kernel to ever really be clean enough to merge in.  Also, the way it was written [didn't allow it to support journals](http://e2compr.sourceforge.net/faq.html).  This latter issue was really the kiss of death for it, as everything with the ext filesystem was moving towards journaling.

The actual old ext2 filesystem doesn't even exist in the kernel any more.  It is all the ext4 code which mounts ext2 filesystems in a sort of compatibility mode.  Compression would have to be written in from scratch at this point.  Corporate support wasn't there for this kind of rewrite, instead it went to other filesystems.

Your options for on-the-fly compression are [ZFS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZFS) and [Btrfs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/btrfs).  Both of them are Copy-on-Write filesystems.  This means when you copy a file, it doesn't take up any extra space until you write to it and change it from the original.  This makes creating snapshots quite easy.  It also can lead to file fragmentation, since when you change a portion of a large file, that portion doesn't overwrite the old part, it is written somewhere new and the old part is marked free.  Large files which see lots of small changes, like database files, can suffer from bad fragmentation.

Of the two, Btrfs would likely be your best bet.  It is mature, included in Ubuntu, supports on-the-fly compression, and it is quite configurable.  For example, if you aren't making snapshots, then autodefrag can help keep the above-mentioned fragmentation low.  Or you can turn off copy-on-write for the whole drive, or for any parts of it where it's not helpful (like /var/lib/mysql).